# Prove the the function's derivative is always 0

Tags: calculus

$$2\arctan{x}+\arcsin{\frac{2x}{1+x^2}}=\pi \text{ for } x\geq1$$
$\text{My approach is this, if we denote function} \\
f(x):=2\arctan{x}+\arcsin{\frac{2x}{1+x^2}}
\text{ Then it is enough to prove that } \\f'(x)=0
\text{, but } f'(x) \text{ is something like this:}$
$$f'(x)=\frac{\frac{2}{x^2+1}-\frac{4x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}}}+\frac{2}{x^2+1}$$
And I do not see how to make this equal to 0 for $x\geq1$ any ideas or hints?

Comment: Do the calcs, it'll work eventually.

Comment: @imranfat I actually calculated the derivate using a calculator to avoid mistakes in calculations

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan I understand, now that $1$ inside the radical, add that to the fraction term to begin with

Comment: @G.Sassatelli. Shall i just $f'(x)=0$ and see for which x it satisfies?

Comment: No. You should calculate that expression using the usual algebra and see that it equals $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=\frac{2(x^2+1)-4x^2}{(x^2+1)^2\sqrt{1-\frac{4x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}}}+\frac2{x^2+1}
\\&=\frac{2x^2+2-4x^2}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{(x^2+1)^2-4x^2}}+\frac2{x^2+1}
\\&=\frac{2(1-x^2)}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2}}+\frac2{x^2+1}
\\&=\frac{2(1-x^2)}{(x^2+1)\cdot|x^2-1|}+\frac2{x^2+1}\end{align}$$

Then since $x\ge1$, we have $|x^2-1|=x^2-1=-(1-x^2)$, so:

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}f'(x)&=-\frac{2\cancel{(1-x^2)}}{(x^2+1)\cancel{(1-x^2)}}+\frac2{x^2+1}
\\&=-\frac2{x^2+1}+\frac2{x^2+1}\\&=0\end{align}$$

So $f(x)=\text{constant}$. Then computing $$f(1)=\left(2\cdot \frac \pi4\right)+\frac\pi2=\pi$$ will give you that $f(x)=\pi$ for all $x\ge 1$.

Comment: Is this the shortest way?

Comment: I believe so. The key points were to get rid of the stacks of fractions, then to try to simplify the square root, and then to do a bit of algebra.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

put $$t=2\arctan (x )$$

with $$t\in [\frac {\pi}{2},\pi) $$

and use

$$\sin (t)=\frac {2x}{1+x^2} $$

then
$$\arcsin (\sin (t))=$$
$$\arcsin (\sin (\pi-t))=$$
$$\pi-t $$

so your function is constant and its derivative is zero.

Comment: Is it fully legal to do so?